# How to restore Mac Normal boot (Login before booting up to macOS)

Tags: macos, startup, restore

After Reinstall macOS Due to Blinking Folder into question mark,
something changed
I boot it up and asks me to login first before booting up
I tried to Reset NVRAM/PRAM but it won't make changes
Is it kind of the exploited Version?

Comment: It seems you have set a firmware password. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455

Comment: You enabled FileVault.  It uses your login credentials to encrypt the drive and will appear as a login screen before you boot.  The only way to disable this is to disable FileVault which I don’t recommend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **System Preferences** » **Security & Privacy** and then click on the  "FileVault" tab.

If it shows that **FileVault** is enabled, then it is normal for it to ask for your password when you first boot the computer.

If that is *not* it, please let me know as a comment.